# Which items should go to the different areas of your base?

Tags: zombies-run

In Zombies, Run! as you run you collect various items. At the end of your run you can use those items to upgrade a number of different areas of your base: the Hospital, Comms, Housing, Armory, Food, or Recreation.

I've noticed that **any** non-story-specific item you collect can be applied to **any** area of the base. But certain items seem to be more effective than others. E.g., a medkit will level up the hospital more than a mobile phone does, but the mobile phone will level up your Comms much more than a medkit. Makes sense.

But other items are not so obvious - does a shirt go to Housing? Recreation? What about a box of light bulbs?

How can I tell what items are most effective in which areas of the base?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to this is here: 
http://checkthis.com/2und

Ultimately, it boils down to color coding, which was my initial thought when I started playing the game.

Orange -> food

Yellow -> housing

Blue -> comms

Green -> hospital

Red -> armory

Grey -> recreational

The article in the link also does a really good job of laying out the individual items and what zone they go to, but without having to look up each individual item every time, the color coding works perfectly.

Comment: I do most of my base management using the web interface in ZombieLink instead of the app, which doesn't have the advantage of color coding (just a dropdown list of items you have). But the link you gave does have the breakdown of all the items so it is still useful. Thanks!